# Certificate common name invalid

Tags: ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate, https

I have a webserver and its domain name is foo.com, if I access the site in https://foo.com I will receive the warning from Chomre browser.

```
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

I searched the web and found this [link](https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-support/csr-generation/ssl-certificate-index.html) saying domain names should follow the specified CN on the certificate. I checked that my certificates CN is actually www.foo.com so when I access the site using https://www.foo.com I am not shown that warning message.

However I can't advise users or customer who will be accessing this site to just type https://www.foo.com so they won't get the warning message. CAn you suggest a solution so that people accessing this site will not be thrown that warning message? Do I need to get another certificate for this or there is just an internal configuration I need to do. I am running a .net application and its using IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a new cert for foo.com (or *.foo.com if you are sending people to other subdomains within foo.com).

Comment: can I ask comodo or any Certificate authority to issue an *.foo.com certificate?

Comment: You can. I've never directly worked with our CA, but we use wildcard domains in our certs and use a well-known CA, so I know it's possible.

Comment: *.example.com does not match https://example.com